# How does Ubuntu handle installing GRUB2 to a partition?

Tags: grub2

I am currently dual-booting Windows and Linux (not Ubuntu), and I am looking to encrypt my Windows partition with Truecrypt.  The Truecrypt bootloader must be installed on the MBR, so it will displace GRUB.  I have read from numerous sources that installing GRUB to a partition is a bad idea, but it is the only solution for my setup.

While I was playing with Ubuntu in a virtual machine, I found that it will install GRUB onto a partition's boot sector without complaint when you choose the advanced partitioning option during installation.  **How does Ubuntu perform this installation?**  I would like to know enough detail so that I may move the concept to any distribution that uses GRUB2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of installing to the device like /dev/sda you install to the partition /dev/sda1.

Command would look like this from a live CD: `sudo grub-install --force --boot-directory=/mnt/drive1/boot /dev/sda1`

I found a [blog post about this issue](http://pzolee.blogs.balabit.com/2010/07/grub2-and-truecrypt-windows-linux-dual-boot-system/), the author says that Truecrypt bootloader acts like a chainloader if ESC is pressed at password prompt.

The ideal solution today would be to use a GPT partition table and UEFI, but unfortunately Truecrypt doesn't seem to support that up until now.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Two questions:  One, why does the `--force` flag need to be used (i.e., why doesn't `grub-install` like installing to a partition)?  Two, GRUB is currently installed on the MBR; do I need to modify my GRUB2 settings before I do this? And, yes, UEFI would be nice, but my computer uses a traditional BIOS.

Comment: GRUB2 tells you that this installation type is not supported (while it is possible) and a bad idea, therefore refusing to do, that's why `--force` is necessary. No you don't need to change your GRUB configuration and if the article is still right, you don't need to add a boot entry to the Windows boot loader (Truecrypt -> Windows Bootloader -> GRUB) either, just hit ESC at the password prompt (Truecrypt -> GRUB).